# Class 'SimpleSoftwareIO\QrCode\QrCodeServiceProvider' not found in laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

my php version is 7.4 and laravel version is 7.0

```
'providers' => [SimpleSoftwareIO\QrCode\QrCodeServiceProvider::class,],
```

Alias

```
'aliases' => ['QrCode' => SimpleSoftwareIO\QrCode\Facades\QrCode::class,],
```

In my composer.json file

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2.5",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": "^3.0"
},
```

[here is error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Knjyk.png)

After adding alias and provider cant able to run any command in laravel root path its shows error like this

```
In ProviderRepository.php line 208: Class 'SimpleSoftwareIO\QrCode\QrCodeServiceProvider' not found
```

Comment: Try `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: did you actually install the package before adding those lines to the config file?

Comment: yes, i have added the alias and provider after installing composer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install the composer using this command

```
composer require simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode
```

Add the following in your web.php file

```
    Route::get('qr-code-g', function () {
    \QrCode::size(500)
            ->format('png')
            ->generate('www.google.com', public_path('images/qrcode.png'));
return view('qrCode');
});
```

in your blade file called **qrcode.blade.php** must be like following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>QR code Generator</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="visible-print text-center">
        <h1>Laravel 7 - QR Code Generator Example</h1> 
        {!! QrCode::size(250)->generate('www.google.com'); !!} 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

No need to add alias and provider in **config/app.php** when you use laravel 7

Need to run following command for install imagemagick

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y imagemagick php-imagick
```

You can check the installation to run the command

```
php -m | grep imagick
```

If its successfully installed, it will show like following

```
imagick
```

Then, need to restart your apache server or reboot your system it will working fine.

[Click Here to check final result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cf9Bc.png)

Comment: where to check in the directory/code if the imagick is installed?

Answer (score 4):

I use Laravel7 and I found solution.
After install QR  "simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": "^3.0"

1. (Don't Add this in config/app.php) 'providers' and 'aliases' on config/app.php

```
#'providers' => [SimpleSoftwareIO\QrCode\QrCodeServiceProvider::class,],
#'aliases' => ['QrCode' => SimpleSoftwareIO\QrCode\Facades\QrCode::class,],
```

2. try add qr in your blade template test.blade.php

```
{!! QrCode::size(250)->generate('www.google.com'); !!}
```

3. it work for me

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers worked for me.
Here is how I fixed it on Laravel 9 with PHP8.

First, we have to install the PHP GD library.

```
sudo apt-get install php-gd
```

Install Simple QRcodde version 4 or higher.

```
composer require simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode "~4" --with-all-dependencies
```

No needs to change config/app.php.

We can simply use it on blade view file:

```
{!! QrCode::size(250)->generate('mailto:SampathPerera@hotmail.com'); !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

Under `config\app.php` update like this:

Providers:

```
SimpleSoftwareIO\QrCode\ServiceProvider::class,
```

Aliases:

```
'QrCode' => SimpleSoftwareIO\QrCode\Facade::class,
```

Or remove this provider and .

Answer (score 1):

In my case i have QrCode Class not found, so i run :

1. Composer remove simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode
2. Composer require simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode (reinstall the class)
3. Try it again.

If you still have the same error after that. try this :

1. Hard code on your example.blade.php file

```css
// Put this on top of your code and outside @if condition (if you have @if condition)
@php 
  use SimpleSoftwareIO\QrCode\Facades\QrCode;
@endphp 

// And then you can use this code below to show your QrCode
{!! QrCode: :size(300)->generate("qrcode_generator_test123") !!}
```

Comment: worked with just step 1 and 2. remove and install.

Answer (score 0):

Execute on command line `composer dump-autoload` and you can call from aliases `\QrCode::method()`

Answer (score -1):

```
Route::get('qr-code-g', function () {
\QrCode::size(500)
        ->format('svg')
        ->generate('www.google.com', public_path('images/qrcode.png'));
```

return view('qrCode');
});**strong text**

**change format to svg**